# c++ generate different class members by different template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

for exmaple, do not create z member for 2D point and create z member for 3D point, like:

```cpp
template <typename T, int DIM>
class Point {
private:
   T x;
   T y;
   #if(DIM==3) { //3 dimension add z;
      T z;
   }
public:
   Point(T x, T y) : x(x), y(y) {}
   #if(DIM==3) {
       Point(T x, T y, T z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
   }


  template <typename U, int D>
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point<U, D>& p) {
    #if(D==3) {
        os << p.x << " " << p.y << " " << p.z;
    } 
    #else {
        os << p.x << " " << p.y;
    }
    
    return os;
  }
};
```

I do not know how to define the template class.

Comment: Personally I would just make 2 classes, a 2d point and a 3d point, unless you want to make it fully generic.

Comment: You could make a member `std::array<T,DIM>`  but in general you cannot generate extra functions based on template arguments. (you can disable/remove some with SFINAE). But I agree with Nathan this is not worth generalizing.

Comment: Do you know what template specialization is, how it works, and how to use it?

Comment: In particular, `Point<T, 4>` or `Point<T, 1>` seems to not make sense in your implementation...

Answer (score 1):

While what you are asking for is possible to achieve via [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization), it is probably easier to just deal with two different types. But lets try to do it anyways.

---

For simplicities sake I used `struct`s instead of `class`es in my code, since their members are marked `public` by default. If this is not the behavior you want, just change them to `class`es and/or mark whatever you want as `public`/`protected`/`private`.

I used the name `PointImpl` for those parts that differ, primarily the members, and later derive the actual `Point` from it. `Point` is going to contain the common methods between both `struct`s.

---

At first we are going to declare our type with its template arguments.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct PointImpl;
```

After this we will need to actually define the two `struct`s with sizes `2` and `3`. One naive solution could be

```
template <typename T>
struct PointImpl<T, 3> {
    T x;
    T y;
    T z;
};
```

and the same for `2` but without the last member. This would however make it harder to write functions that can take `PointImpl`s with different sizes like your `std::ostream& operator<<` overload. You could use template specialization on those, but there is an easier way. We are just going to add a subscript operator.

```
const T& operator[](std::size_t idx) const {
    switch (idx) {
        case 0:
            return x;
        case 1:
            return y;
        case 2:
            return z;
        default:
            throw std::out_of_range("Point<T, 3>::operator[] access out of bounds!");
    }
}
```

This allows us to access all members with just an index and not the actual name of the member (implement the same for size `2` again without the `case 2` and change the error message).

---

We now have the basic building blocks for the final `Point` and can derive it from `PointImpl`.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Point : PointImpl<T, N> {
};
```

You can now add whatever methods you want/need in this `Point`s body. One important part is the `operator[]`.

```
T& operator[](std::size_t idx) {
    return const_cast<T&>(std::as_const(*this)[idx]);
}
```

In this snippet we first apply `const` to `*this` and then call its `operator[]` from there on. Since we already implemented a `const T& operator[] const` in `PointImpl` this works perfectly fine. Then we remove the previously applied `const` again so we can return just a `T&`.
This would now shadow the `const` version in the `PointImpl` and to fix this we add the following line in the `Point`s body:

```
using PointImpl<T, N>::operator[];
```

---

From here on the rest gets pretty easy. You could add different methods to the `Point` like these:

```
std::size_t size() const {
    return N;
}

void zero(T defaultValue = {}) {
    for (std::size_t i{ 0 }; i < N; ++i) {
        (*this)[i] = defaultValue;
    }
}

friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& point) {
    for (std::size_t i{ 0 }; i < N - 1; ++i) {
        os << point[i] << ' ';
    }
    os << point[N - 1];
    return os;
}
```

---

Note that using `Point` with a size other than `2` or `3` will result in a compilation error since there is no `PointImpl` defined for those.

[live example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMwA7KSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIACspAAOqAqETgwe3r4BwemZjgLhkTEs8YkpdpgO2UIETMQEuT5%2BQbaY9iUMjc0EZdFxCcm2TS1t%2BZ0KE4MRw5WjSQCUtqhexMjsHOb%2BEcjeWADUJv5uTrPEmKxn2CYaAIJ7B0eYp%2BezWKrbqQR3D2eZn2DEOXhOZzcXkctEIAE8AU9AQRMCxUgYUR83AQ4alGKx3gAVUjHL4gECZABemAA%2BgRjlFEY8rl4HMdlKgIgQAJJo2hnKxIp4ovlMTGQnF45hsY6Epkstkcrm89GQ4nHMx3U6BQWPY762XHVQCwEGw0I/y600GtAMWay8wANmOqDxxDFJBMSSsSQAIhAyRS8NS6cc8OhVCtjrb7SYddazfqFAB3QjIBDHCDhyPa3WJ/PRphKY4aEAJgv564ETYMI0mp4Vs2iYtcMsNxuVzDV4i1i15jvHLBUJheWgENt6gdmggIYioZOkgjockbAg01BUGnuoyYCDmMxKwRqkma/zYFduj3EL0%2B33HJjIbYKBQu6EuqjHWIbBjoBRgMD7is9aTvmca%2BuWYGApBlpQcKqLomK7wSri%2BIynKZ6Agq9KHjyfLHsc/hanG/b6oSdYwe2pHHH25ZkZSwHljG9JymYzqugkV43l6/qBlStL0tmUZMbm5ZmimaYZlmEZRsRokFs27ylnJHZVjW5EkY2CnHK2ymNqpPbUcBU5aWYE5Tma%2Bm1vRFEgY2Q4jmOZnmfqM5zgugaruum7bsAu77jh%2BGEWeF4cUQ17etx96Ppgz6vvSG6ft%2Bv7/oBRkFpBlHauBSKBOBNnIvBGJIeckqoUSJK8cG/EMvKBDEKy2GcoIxwgOyTW4aq5zqoyZ4iZlLFsZeYVcX6AZLuSfGhoJfW2RZXZqUxNLNv8XVOncY3LiARZLQIswQAAVDOeAKEB3rZtxQE2WaGW2V4mRGG1yp4V1JI9eeIDse6w0RX6DGZZVIb0nxEBCbt9KyZlc3drWPUaTd5YAG6cugxzUnOEBkfZo4EAAamIXjFXesm5TJ8aQwa/DEJmAPVXgxElllAphliNWWqcljWHgpMaRWB1HSdN5036Hx3ljY5494mBpaBuUQbLQq2VQxB4K4i6bRkdU3CwToukNnrnJCG0rlcWs6xkJLCQFrHHOkXLc7plPU%2BNQaA2G9MaIzbN4CzUTHAAtNpTPWJz9vk/mGRYpCNvtYLkWQlHYAcMcifS4mN0VhH8fnNHXI3r7AdcNxqdQ2pGSp/Dsv5U8XLHCwTARCDM1mgF5xcieWqpGY6Cpy3FyCCSQXYDb/jd1Xtmd%2BgAB0qgi9pwKpxPk9wrPkhJI6qeBmgb5Z24Ntd5H2eBq4/Jj2ai9o6gIMb87W/gwb2cTwfu9Hz%2BJ9WplqQj9Ps8AJwAByBAXl/ZeZw7yOiSJIIBU9KSz38GYQuV0DSb1XE/YeKMd5q3JMfP6tlLIlgYrlDgaxaCcCSLwPwHAtCkFQJwNwwdLCkg2FsJCwIeCkHHJQohawADWIBJB/0nmYVejopAaH8EkDQADAhmH0JwSQ5DNC8BoRwXgCgQAaHYYotYcBYAwEQCgVAaI6AJHIJQNARj6CJGAFwOBfA6AomIGoiAsRFGkFiBEZocJOBsPccwYgcIADysRtB1A4Ww8xbBBABIYLQLxnDSBYFiF4YAbgxC0DUdwXgWA65GHEPE/A1x6gIxiq4zAqg6jQh2FQrk3RXGwliO6fxHgsCuLqngFg3iiF8AMMABQOMVbJgCVKTpMhBAiDEOwKQoz5BKDUK43QXB9CGGMPQmw9S1GQDWK6XoGS/YAHU0n%2Bz2WUuqTAjkJDnMQJRxTiDKywBskGXQejZBcD%2BKYfhFlhAWBUKoegihZAEO8v5GQAUMCGD80Yizaj1AEP0SYnh2h6Ghb0OF8xygjESFCuYQKsUDHBRiiQawFBMO2IS2RHAyGkAoVQ5RRo/6Oj9o6SQxxgCPm0v4QRmZcCEBIOzfwXAVi8A4VoFYawEA3CwIkR5vCkhcEnoECB/g/5JB/kyn%2BXAzBmB/uS%2BRpAOkSKpa45Rqj1GaM4dovREAkCrlSNCUxEBzGpGMcQKIBJOCqHpYy5lrLkDssEbwTA%2BAwrhj0PwMZohxBTLDTMlQ6h4kLNIMmd0qROnENIQo%2BJyiAnQltfFD8HqGVMpZWymxnKIAeAsQkPlAqhVaLFRK0YjySEcF1fqjR1KlGcBNRo4VXDSAyrlQqyQSqVVqo1Vq8l/gM00q7WakVaaOBmGnZ2lRc6%2B03MyM4SQQA)

---

#### Edit:

If you can use a more recent version of C++ (C++20 or later) you can use a combination of [`std::conditional_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) and [`[[no_unique_address]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address) with an empty `struct`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

struct empty{};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
    requires (N == 2 || N == 3)
struct Point {
    T x;
    T y;
    
    [[no_unique_address]] std::conditional_t<N == 3, T, empty> z;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& point) {
        os << point.x << ' ' << point.y;
        if constexpr (N == 3) {
            os << ' ' << point.z;
        }
        return os;
    }
};

static_assert(sizeof(Point<int, 2>) == 2 * sizeof(int));
static_assert(sizeof(Point<int, 3>) == 3 * sizeof(int));
```

<sub>If you are using msvc you will have to repalce `[[no_unique_address]]` with `[[msvc::no_unique_address]]`.</sub>

Comment: I want a more elegant way - define class Point once for both of Pont 2D and Point 3D?

Comment: @wkgreat I added a second way to implement it which might be a bit easier/cleaner, however it uses C++20.

Comment: Thanks for showing a use case for no_unique_address! Cool example!

Comment: @Klaus Yeah I like it too :). I actually didn't know about that feature before and stumbled upon it while researching for a better solution than the previous one with the template specialization.

Answer (score 0):

you can also follow a pattern similar to this:
https://github.com/ptrefall/geomod2specialeffects/blob/master/depends/GMLib/gmPoint.h
with spezializations for 2d and 3d:
https://github.com/ptrefall/geomod2specialeffects/blob/master/depends/GMLib/gmPoint2D.h

It is not one class for both 2d and 3d, but the might be different spezializations for 2d and 3d,but none that i can think of at the moment.